# How can I prove that if $a^7 = b^7$ then $a=b$, with $ a,b \in \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, order-theory, foundations

I've tried with divisibility, meaning that since $a$ divides $a^7$, then $a$ divides $b^7$ and in the same way b divides $a^7$, but I can't seem to go further than this. What properties of the integers could I use to solve this?

Comment: Unique prime factorisation is one option. Noting that $n \mapsto n^7$ is strictly increasing is another.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:$$a^7-b^7=(a-b)(a^6+a^5b+...+b^6)=0$$ $$a^6+a^5b+...+b^6$$ is always.....

Comment: Why downvote???

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a>b\ge0$ and set $a=b+c$, with $c>0$. Then
$$
a^7-b^7=(b+c)^7-b^7=\sum_{k=1}^7\binom{7}{k}b^{7-k}c^k>0
$$
Therefore $a^7>b^7$.

If $a>0\ge b$, then clearly $a^7>b^7$.

If $0\ge a>b$, then $0\le -a<-b$, so by the first step we get $(-b)^7>(-a)^7$ that implies $a^7>b^7$.

So we have proved that, in any case, $a>b$ implies $a^7>b^7$. Of course $a<b$ implies $a^7<b^7$ and, putting these together, we have that $a\ne b$ implies $a^7\ne b^7$.

---

You can also do it with factorization. Suppose $a^7=b^7$, with $a>0$ and $b>0$ (since $7$ is odd, it is not restrictive).

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $a$ and let $r$ be the maximum exponent such that $p^r$ divides $a$. Then $p^{7r}$ also divides $b^7$. In particular $p$ divides $b^7$, hence it divides $b$. Let $s$ be the maximum exponent such that $p^s$ divides $b$. Then $p^{7s}$ divides $b^7$, so $7r\le 7s$ and $r\le s$. By reversing the roles of $a$ and $b$, we get that $s\le r$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: $a=b$ iff $v_p(a)=v_p(b)$ for all primes $p$

$v_p(x)$ is the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $x$ so that
$$
x=\prod_p p^{v_p(x)}
$$

Comment: What does $vp(a)$ means?

Comment: @Ben-ZT The exponent that has $p$ in the factorization of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|>|b|$ then $|a^7|>|b^7|$. Similarly if $|a|<|b|$. So $|a|=|b|$. Since $a^7=b^7$ and $7$ is odd, $a$ and $b$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 1):

$a^7-b^7=(a-b)a^6p(\frac ba)=0$ where $p(x)=x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is the cyclotomic polynomial of degree $6=7-1$ and all of these polynomials with degree $p-1$ where $p$ prime it is well known to be irreducible so $a^6p(\frac ba)\ne 0$ since $(a,b)\in \mathbb Z^2$. Hence  $a-b=0$

Answer (score 0):

If $a^7 = b^7$,
then
$0
=a^7-b^7
= a^7(1-(b/a)^7)
$.

Consider
$f(x) = 1-x^7
$.
$f(1) = 0$.
$f'(x)
=-7x^6
\le 0
$
since
$x^6 \ge 0$
with equality only if
$x = 0$.

Therefore
$f(x)$
can have at most
one real root
since it is
decreasing everywhere
except zero
where it is
zero.

Therefore
$1-x^7$
can have at most one real root.
Since $f(1) = 0$,
that is its only real root.

This works for
$a^{2n+1}-b^{2n+1}$
for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: Because I wanted to do it this way.